# Sheets query: Losing string values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

How can I get `=query` to handle a column of mixed numbers and strings?

I have a column of accounts names.  Some are purely numeric (e.g. 123), and some are alphanumeric ("x456").

```
    A
  123
  123
x456
x456
```

I expect this query

```
=query(A2:A5,"select A")
```

to return the data for all cells, but it filters out the alphanumeric cells,
so my returned data is only

```
123
123
```

and not the expected

```
  123
  123
x456
x456
```

How can I structure my query to include the missing alphanumeric data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a workaround to enable two differing data types to be pulled in a Google Sheets query?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106224/is-there-a-workaround-to-enable-two-differing-data-types-to-be-pulled-in-a-googl)

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?